# Could not load file or assembly 'mydllfile.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: asp.net, .net, deployment, assemblies, publish

Whenever i add new dll in my application in bin folder and access that dll it gives me following error:

> Could not load file or assembly '~\bin\mydll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Do the .dll's you are using contain native code? If so this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11343920/771034

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dependency Walker Tool - it shows you what library in dependency is missing.

If the missing library is MFC or any Visual C++ runtime, then install  theMicrosoft redistributable package (it should be from the same Visual Studio on which you're building the DLL).

Also, you can set the static linking to MFC or VC++ Runtime Libraries. In that case, you will not need to put Visual C++ runtime into the setup

> This configure in project settings C/C++ -> Code Generation node - use MT for Release and MTd for Debug

MFC runtime is configured on General project tab.